# Global variable cross-thread not updating

Tags: python, multithreading

I've knocked the below up as a demo of what I'm seeing.

Basically, on keydown then Z should be set to 2 and the print loop in show_thread should output this new value but even if I press keys, the output is still just saying "Z is 1"

From my checks, it seems that Z isn't being updated under if L: but I can't work out why.

I've also tried adding in

```
delay(1000)
Z = 999
```

underneath the thread creations and then the output says "Z is 1" for 10 seconds and then says (and stays saying) "Z is 999"

```
import time
import thread

def input_thread(L):
    derp = raw_input()
    L.append(derp)

def show_thread(foo):
    while 1:
        print "Z is " + `Z`
        print "\n"
        time.sleep(2)

def main():
    global Z
    L = []
    thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (L,))
    thread.start_new_thread(show_thread, (1,))

    while 1:
        if L:
            Z = 2
            print L[0]
            print "\n"

Z = 1
main()
```

Comment: Works for me with Python 2.7.3 on Linux 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to mhlester's answer. You need to remove the `print` statement in the `main` function.

```
import time
import thread

def input_thread(L):
    derp = raw_input()
    L.append(derp)

def show_thread(foo):
    while 1:
        print "Z is " + repr(Z) # Do not use backtick(`). Use `repr`
        print "\n"
        time.sleep(2)

def main():
    global Z  # declare `Z` as global
    L = []
    thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (L,))
    thread.start_new_thread(show_thread, (1,))

    while 1:
        if L:
            Z = 2
            # Remove following print statements,
            #   otherwise it will cover the terminal with empty lines.
            #print L[0]  <---------
            #print "\n"  <---------

Z = 1
main()
```

Comment: Thanks, That's been really helpful as my key entry is still echo'd back to me so can't have been my code causing that to happen.

As such, I'm guessing the if L: block is never actually being hit and so that's why the variable (Z) update is never happening!

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, `Z` is a local variable, not changing the global variable. You seem aware of the concept of global by including it in the title of your post, but you're not using it in the code. add `global Z` to the top of `main()`

```
def main():
    global Z   # <--- here
    L = []
    thread.start_new_thread(input_thread, (L,))
    thread.start_new_thread(show_thread, (1,))

    while 1:
        if L:
            Z = 2
            print L[0]
            print "\n"
```

Or refactor the code to use a `class`, so you have a `self.Z` or similar

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me although the global addition still didn't work - it just keeps printing "Z is 1"

If I was to under the thread.start_new_thread blocks add a DELAY(10) and then Z=50 then the print will start saying Z=50 after 10 seconds so the global is working in main() but somehow not in the if statement...

I'm really confused!